# Chaining multiple CAAnimation in a AVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, core-animation

I'm trying to export a video file with a `CALayer` overlay and multiple attached `CAAnimation` chained over time. For this i am using  `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool`.

My `CABasicAnimation` are chained by offsetting their `beginTime`.
Inside `animationDidStop(_:finished:)` I update the animated property of the corresponding `CALayer`.

I've removed most of the boilerplate from the code sample below...

```
/* AnimationChainer is A simple class whose instance will
 * update a CALayer's model to reflect the final state of
 * the animation. a translation on the y-axis in this case. */

class AnimationChainer: NSObject, CAAnimationDelegate {

  func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    let val = anim.value(forKey: "yTranslation") as! CGFloat
    let layer = anim.value(forKey: "layer") as! CALayer
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
    layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0.0, val, 0.0)
    CATransaction.commit()
  }

}

/* animation setup - a layer going up by 200pt then back to original pos. */

let chainer: AnimationChainer!
let interval = 2
let movingLayer = CALayer()

let translateOnceAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.y")
translateOnceAnimation.duration = 0.4
translateOnceAnimation.fromValue = 0
translateOnceAnimation.byValue = -200
translateOnceAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
translateOnceAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
translateOnceAnimation.setValue(-200, forKey: "yTranslation")
translateOnceAnimation.setValue(movingLayer, forKey: "layer")
translateOnceAnimation.delegate = chainer
translateOnceAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero

let translateTwiceAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.translation.y")
translateTwiceAnimation.duration = 0.4
translateTwiceAnimation.fromValue = -200
translateTwiceAnimation.byValue = 200
translateTwiceAnimation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
translateTwiceAnimation.fillMode = .forwards
translateTwiceAnimation.setValue(0.0, forKey: "yTranslation")
translateTwiceAnimation.setValue(movingLayer, forKey: "layer")
translateTwiceAnimation.delegate = chainer
translateTwiceAnimation.beginTime = AVCoreAnimationBeginTimeAtZero + interval

movingLayer.add(translateOnceAnimation, forKey: nil)
movingLayer.add(translateTwiceAnimation, forKey: nil)

let parentLayer = CALayer()
parentLayer.addSublayer(movingLayer)

/* end of animation setup */

let compo: AVMutableComposition!
let videoCompo: AVMutableVideoComposition!
let videoLayer: CALayer!

videoCompo.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)

let exporter = AVAssetExportSession(asset: compo, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
exporter?.videoComposition = videoCompo
exporter?.exportAsynchronously {
  self.exportDidFinish(exporter!)
}
```

It works well when I bind the animated layer on a view controller's root-view.
But whenever i use it with `AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool` the `animationDidStop(_:finished:)` are called but in a random order.
Resulting in a wrong final state for the animated property.

The weirdest thing is that if I put a breakpoint inside `animationDidStop(_:finished:)` it works!

Another disturbing result: if I remove delegates it still works... probably due to the fillMode. but I cannot explain it completely.

Comment: I doubt that your transaction-based approach can work because as the video is created by mapping the animation onto the video there is no real transaction.

Comment: The transaction is here only to disable implicit animations. I've just edited the final paragraph to better reflect my results

Comment: @matt i've just commented-out the transaction and the animation doesn't work on the video export anymore.

Comment: Your editing seems to me to confirm what I said earlier. You can't use `animationDidStop` in this context because the animation never truly runs in the normal sense. It is reenacted in the shadow-play context of video time.

Comment: @matt what do you mean by 'shadow-play context ' ? if i cannot use `animationDidStop` what other options do i have to sequentially update `CALayer`'s model ?

Comment: Not only what Matt is saying but in AVFoundation I have found that you cannot have two different animations on the same layer property of a layer. In your instance “transform.translation.y”. Only one can be applied or neither will work. That’s why you said they don’t work anymore. They need to be keyframe animations to work. This is unwritten rule I have found to be true. It may be documented somewhere but I have never seen it.

Comment: And by keyframe I mean a single keyframe animation on that layer property

Comment: @agibson007 i believe your are wrong on this statement

Comment: Why would one downvote this question ? It clearly address a blindspot of AVFoundation

Comment: @louisf the part about applying the same animation twice?  Try something simple like breaking an opacity fade in and fade out into 2 animations and let me know how it works.  Pretty sure it needs to be a keyframe.

Answer (score 2):

In real life, animations run within a CATransaction, against the wall clock. They have a beginning, a middle, and an end, as it were. The animation server checks the situation in real time, on every turn of the runloop, and advances the frames as needed.

But with an AVSynchronizedLayer or an AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool, there is no wall clock involved; there is no animation server. The animation is frozen, and its frames are mapped through calculation to the video's timecodes. Thus, techniques based around transactions don't work; all you have is the individual frames.

As you rightly say, the fill mode is a big help in this situation.